In Rust, is it possible to expand a trait with additional provided methods?
Is it possible to add expand a trait with additional provided methods? For example, I have an iterator and I want to write it.foobar() instead of foobar(it). I might try something like this:
trait PrintIterator: Iterator<Item: Display> {
    fn print_all(self)
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        self.for_each(|x| println!("{}", x))
    }
}

This doesn't work however, because when I try to use it, I get a compile error:
    let x = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    x.iter().print_all();

error[E0599]: no method named `print_all` found for struct `std::slice::Iter` in the current scope
  --> main.rs:15:14
   |
15 |     x.iter().print_all();
   |              ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Iter<'_, &str>`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `PrintIterator` defines an item `print_all`, perhaps you need to implement it
  --> main.rs:3:1
   |
3  | trait PrintIterator: Iterator<Item: Display> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

So apparently, I'd have to explicitly implement PrintIterator for every type that implements Iterator. Given that PrintIterator doesn't have any required methods, it should work everywhere where Iterator works, given that Item implements Display. Is there any way to circumvent this?
